# Homebrew failing to download autoconf package

Tags: bash, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am attempting to install the package autoconf on my mac because I need to use autoreconf to install LHAPDF for some particle collision simulations

I am a little confused about why homebrew is failing to install this package.
After the command:

`brew install autoconf`

I get the following output and error:

> `
> ==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
>
> ==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
> ############################################################################################################################################################# 100.0%
> ==> Fetching dependencies for autoconf: m4
> ==> Fetching m4
> ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/m4/manifests/1.4.19
> Error: autoconf: Failed to download resource "m4_bottle_manifest"
> Failure while executing; /usr/bin/env /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.0.15\ \(Macintosh\;\ arm64\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 13.2.1\)\ curl/7.86.0 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --header Accept:\ application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1\+json --header Authorization:\ Bearer\ QQ== --fail --location --silent --head --request GET https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/m4/manifests/1.4.19 exited with 22. Here's the output:
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503
> HTTP/2 503
> content-type: application/json
> docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
> date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 09:28:37 GMT
> content-length: 68
> x-github-request-id: C53C:A4DD:4B4B0C:4DD39E:644A403F
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503
> HTTP/2 503
> content-type: application/json
> docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
> date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 09:28:45 GMT
> content-length: 68
> x-github-request-id: C53C:A4DD:4B4ED1:4DD755:644A4045
>
> HTTP/2 503
> content-type: application/json
> docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
> date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 09:28:53 GMT
> content-length: 68
> x-github-request-id: C53C:A4DD:4B52B0:4DDB2C:644A404D
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 503
> HTTP/2 503
> content-type: application/json
> docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0
> date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 09:29:03 GMT
> content-length: 68
> x-github-request-id: C53C:A4DD:4B57C6:4DE041:644A4055
> `

Does this just mean that the server is down?
I would appreciate any advice you have. Thank you